# Can't use SCSS in React

Tags: reactjs, sass

Hello everyone I just added sass in all possible ways to my app by `npm install sass` by `npm install node-sass` by `yarn add sass-loader` even by `sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass` all these commands by `yarn` also and my app tells me to add sass :/
[image: Packages.json]

[image: App.js]

[image: Error]

Comment: "`sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass`" - you **really** shouldn't do that - a malicious npm package could destroy your entire system or plant a kernel-mode rootkit/spyware program.

Comment: I read it in stackoverflow's other threads :/ but it didn't work also so...

Comment: Did you install `node-sass` globally? If no install it `npm install -g node-sass` globally

Comment: I'm sure I did because I did all possible variations of node-sass and sass

Comment: Can you stop the server and delete the `node_modules` and re-run `npm install` or `yarn`, whichever you use?

Comment: please try this one

`npm install node-sass --save`
or
`yarn add node-sass`

for more information: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/

Which version of `yarn` you are using?

Comment: @senta yeah I deleted manually then installed again didn't work

Comment: @AbhilashKaramana I did it also :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I finally did it, I don't know for sure but I guess when installing a new thing `node sass` or anything you should re-run the react app refresh or even `ctrl+f5` won't work I have right now 2 tabs of my react app one is `http://localhost:3000/` the other one `http://localhost:3001` I commanded `yarn start` again after installing and it work while the first one is still open and it doesn't work

Hope this will help others

Answer (score 0):

Below is the documented process for adding sass to react app using yarn

```
yarn add node-sass
```

Rename the `.css` files to `.scss` and update the import statements.

I just did it on my machine and it works.

Comment: Yeah I did it look at my images everything is done as you told, still doesn't work :/

Comment: According to your screenshots,  You have a blank app, please generate new app and then run ` yarn add node-sass`

Comment: I don't understand :/

Comment: 1. Generate a new app by `npx create-react-app my-app`   2. Run `yarn add node-sass` 3. Change the filenames and imports.  Hope it should work

Comment: Why should I create a new app I did a lot of work in this one :/

Comment: Ohh I understand, then remove sass from your package.json, remove the node modules folder and run yarn install again. Make sure node-sass is still in package.json

Comment: I did it once but I will try again

Comment: That didn't work but I got the answer I don't know hi :/